# swig macro $descriptor within helper function

Tags: python, c++, swig

**Intro**

My typical swig interface file is similar to the following:

```
%{ //COPY THIS BLOCK AS IS
    #include <headers.h>

    static CppClass* get_CppClass_from_swig_object(PyObject* obj)
    {
        void* self_obj = nullptr;
        int ok = SWIG_Python_ConvertPtr(obj, &self_obj, SWIGTYPE_p_CppClass, 0);
        if(!SWIG_IsOK(ok))
        {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Object must be a CppClass");
            return nullptr;
        }

        return reinterpret_cast<CppClass*>(self_obj);
    }

    static CppClass convert_to_CppClass(PyObject* py_obj)
    {
        CppClass* converted_ptr = get_CppClass_from_swig_object(py_obj);
        if(converted_ptr==nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("Python object is not a CppClass");

        return CppClass(*converted_ptr);
    }
%}


%typemap(in) std::vector<CppClass>& (std::vector<CppClass> temp) {
    try{
        temp = SequenceConverter::to_vector<CppClass>($input, convert_to_CppClass);
        $1 = &temp;
    }catch(std::exception& e){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, e.what());
        SWIG_fail;
    }
}

%typemap(typecheck, precedence=SWIG_TYPECHECK_CPPCLASS_VECTOR) std::vector<CppClass>& {
    $1 = 0;
    if(PyTuple_Check($input))
        $1 = 1;
    else if(PyList_Check($input))
        $1 = 1;
}


class CppClass
{
public:
    CppClass();
    CppClass(const CppClass& other);

    //other methods
};
```

but I would like to avoid explicitly using `SWIGTYPE_p_CppClass` within `get_CppClass_from_swig_object`.

As is, it is not possible to use the `$descriptor(CppClass)` swig macro as I would like to, because the `%{ ... %}` block is copied as -is rather than interpreted by swig, and so the `$descriptor` swig macro would not be interpreted. On the other hand, if i would remove the `%` and use a `{ ... }` block, swig would try and wrap the whole `get_CppClass_from_swig_object` and `convert_to_CppClass` classes rather than simply defining them so they can be used in the typemap.

**Question**

How can I change my file structure and allow using `$descriptor` macro within the conversion helpers?

**TL;DR**

- `%{...%}` blocks are neither preprocessed nor wrapped by swig
- `{...}` blocks are both preprocessed and wrapped ( but small pieces can be prevented from swig preprocessing with a preceding `%` )
- How can I make swig preprocess but not wrap a piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to make the contents of `%{...%}` be preprocessed, but not wrapped - for most of what the preprocessor does it relies on a typemap to actually be instantiated to populate the substitution information (although `$descriptor` could still work and I've wished for it in the past).

My usual solution is to pass the SWIG type info as an argument into functions like that, for example:

```
%{ //COPY THIS BLOCK AS IS
    #include <headers.h>

    static CppClass* get_CppClass_from_swig_object(PyObject* obj, swig_type_info *ty) 
    {
        //... use ty instead of $descriptor here
```

Which means that when you use `get_CppClass_from_swig_object` in a typemap all you need to do is use `$1_descriptor` or `$descriptor` to get the correct value for the second argument.